# Best WPF open source projects

Tags: .net, wpf, open-source

I have programmed with WPF for more than a year. When I started there weren't so many examples and guidelines to follow, now the situation is much more better.

I would like to ask you some help in listing the best WPF (open) source code examples or projects that you suggest to study in order to learn more about project structure, best practices, etc.

Thank you,
Marco

Comment: wpf itself is open source now.https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/12/04/announcing-open-source-of-wpf-windows-forms-and-winui-at-microsoft-connect-2018/

Comment: Lei Yang is correct, as of now, WPF is now open source (see https://github.com/dotnet/wpf )

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If for you it is enough to have the source available (but not really *open* regarding the license) I still consider very useful FamilyShow (http://www.vertigo.com/FamilyShow.aspx) and Prism (http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) for an approach at a different "scale".

Comment: thanks a lot for the FamilyShow link, it seems really interesting

Answer (score 8):

[Crack.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/cracknetproject) and [Prism](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) come to mind.

Answer (score 7):

You might be interested in the sample applications of the [**WPF Application Framework (WAF)**](http://waf.codeplex.com). They show:

- View composition
- UI Workflow (Wizards)
- Command binding / Shortcut Keys
- MVVM pattern, Unit Testing
- Validation
- Entity Framework
- Open/Save FileDialog
- Print Preview / Print Dialog
- Localization

Comment: do you think this waf is suitable for data-centric-game development? for example some sport manager without animations?

Answer (score 4):

Although I haven't looked at it much myself, I've heard really good things about [Caliburn](http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn) It's an open source framework to help you build applications in SL and WPF using best practices and patterns such as MVC and MVVM.

Answer (score 3):

Still not really "open", but very interesting
MSDN Reader http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/msdnreader

Answer (score 1):

Couple more from codeplex:

- [Timeline Control for WPF and Silverlight](http://timeline.codeplex.com/)
- [Color Wheel Controls for WPF and Silverlight](http://color.codeplex.com/)